# ProviderName returns empty string for google login under .Net Framework 4.0 Webform

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, dotnetopenauth

I'm trying to authenticate web app using Google sign-in option. I have tried with below options ( as I don't want to use .net 4.0> frameworks)

- .Net Framework 4.0
- Webforms

Option 1:

```
OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.AddGoogle();
```

This is default option provided under AuthConfig.cs 
To get Google login option I have uncommented the above line

Giving Error as  Sequence contains no elements. No OpenID endpoint found.

Option 2 :

```
var client = new GoogleOAuth2Client("clientId", "secretId");
var extraData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
OpenAuth.AuthenticationClients.Add("Google", () => client, extraData);
```

If I try with above option, when I click on google login, it is taking me to Google Sign in Page, after successful login, while request coming back to the application, `OpenAuth.GetProviderNameFromCurrentRequest();` returns empty string. as per the below condition, it is taking me to the login page again. For Facebook and Twitter login, it is returning respective provider name except for the google.

```
ProviderName = OpenAuth.GetProviderNameFromCurrentRequest();
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ProviderName))
{
     Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl);
}
```

What is the reason behind it and what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you went with option 2 you need to change RegisterExternalLogin.aspx to the following

```
{GoogleOAuth2Client.RewriteRequest();
ProviderName = OpenAuth.GetProviderNameFromCurrentRequest();}
```

This will allow the `ProviderName` to be found.

You also need to add `{using DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2;}`